# Unexpected behavior of preg_replace() with regular expression containing \h on à

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am seeing the following unexpected behavior in PHPs `preg_replace()`:

Running

```
echo("'".preg_replace('#\h\h+#', ' ', 'à')."'\n");
echo("'".preg_replace('#\h\h+#', ' ', 'à ')."'\n");
echo("'".preg_replace('#\h\h+#', ' ', 'á')."'\n");
echo("'".preg_replace('#\h\h+#', ' ', 'á ')."'\n");
echo("'".preg_replace('#\h+#', ' ', 'à ')."'\n");
echo("'".preg_replace('#\h#', ' ', 'à ')."'\n");
```

yields the output

```
'à'
'Ã '
'á'
'á '
'Ã '
'Ã  '
```

Why is the 'à' in some cases replaced by 'Ã '?

Shouldn't my regular expression only replace certain occurrence of horizontal white space characters with a single space and leave all other characters alone?

Comment: Different encoding in editor/IDE and server/web?

Comment: Use it with `u` modifier, e.g. `'#\h+#u'`.

Comment: That does the trick! I somehow implicitly assumed that at least newer versions of php should by default work with unicode, but that is apparently not the case. Thanks!